# How do I set php to start on reboot?

Tags: php-7, ubuntu-16.04, kirby

I am using Kirby on Ubuntu 16.04, and every time I reboot I have to login on my server, go to my website folder and type

```
sudo php -S 0.0.0.0:80
```

for the server to start.

What's a correct way of getting this to start automatically after a reboot?

Sorry for the trivial question, I just don't seem to be able to find a simple answer on the web...

Comment: Just to make sure: you're only using `php -S` for testing, I would hope. It's not safe or practical for production sites.

Comment: @Andrea right now I'm in testing, but I was planning to release it that way. That's all I got from Kirby CMS docs... What is the appropriate way?

Comment: Configure a proper web server such as nginx or Apache. PHP's development web server is not secure or reliable in production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use root's crontab with `@reboot` directive. Edit it with `sudo crontab -e`

```
@reboot cd /path/to/directory && php -S 0.0.0.0:80
```

Notice that there is no `sudo` before the `php` command, because it's run from root's crontab.